# How to detect iOS7 Safari height change on scrolling - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, mobile-safari

In Safari on iPhone iOS7 a scroll down will show the menus at the top and bottom and a scroll up will hide them - effectively changing the height of the screen.

How do I listen for this slight change in height?

I have an element that changes height depending on the height of the screen, but in iOS7 it's not really behaving well.

Comment: Is it really a height change? I doubt so.

Comment: Does the `resize` event fire when this happens? If so you can check for that.

Comment: I'm checking for resize already... "I have an element that changes height depending on the height of the screen".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In a recent React project I set a CSS var to the `window.innerHeight` on resize.

```
const setAppHeight = (): void => {
  const doc = document.documentElement;
  doc.style.setProperty('--app-height', `${window.innerHeight}px`);
};

const debouncedEventHandler = useMemo(
  () => debounce(setAppHeight, 300),
  [],
);

useEffect(() => {
  window.addEventListener('resize', debouncedEventHandler);
  setAppHeight();

  return () => {
    debouncedEventHandler.cancel();
  };
}, []);
```

That var was set normally in CSS and used whenever something needed

```
:root {
  --app-height: 100%;
}

.whatever {
  height: var(--app-height);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To listen to window resize events we can use `window.addEventListener("resize", myFunction);`
or using jQuery `$(window).resize(myFunction());`

I had a related problem but reversed -- a small window resize that happens on-scroll on iOS devices was unnecessarily triggering my on-resize logic.

One workaround can be just ignoring a small vertical resize (approx 40px should be ok)

An example solution (using jQuery)

```
  const ignoreVerticalResizeTreshold= 40;
  let vpHeight= 0;
  let vpWidth= 0;
  

  $(window).resize(function() {


      // Do stuff (on any window resize event)


      // return if no horizontal resize happened and vertical resize is below the set treshold
      if ($(window).innerWidth() === vpWidth && (($(window).innerHeight() >= (vpHeight - ignoreVerticalResizeTreshold / 2)) || ($(window).innerHeight() <= (vpHeight + ignoreVerticalResizeTreshold / 2)))) {
        return;
      }
  
  
      // Do more stuff
  
  
      vpHeight = $(window).innerHeight();
      vpWidth = $(window).innerWidth();

  });
```